# Specific user cannot be added to Room Appointment Exhange Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

This only happens with one user and any room in outlook.

Making meeting in  - outlook 2010 > meeting > add user > click rooms > choose room > room information flashes on the screen and then is removed from the locations. Anyone that has tried can add anyone else to the meeting and the room but not the special user. It happens with any room and only that user.

Notes: Global company, multiple exchange servers, user just recently migrated from Europe server to American Server. Thats the only thing that happened recently.

Symptoms: Under "Suggested Times" in exchange it reads : suggestions cannot be provided because free/busy data could not be retrieved.

We have checked multiple computers, multiple install versions of windows, checked permissions on that account in the Exchange server, they all look good.

Thanks in advance.